# Combine two dictionaries into one in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

after having carried out unsuccessful research and tests, I have decided to write here. I am trying to merge two dictionaries with the same key into one dictionary by merging the duplicate values.
Specifically, I have this code:
schools  =

```
firestore.collection('schools').document(regione).collection(provincia).document(comune).collections()
message = []
for collection in schools:
    print(collection.id)
    for doc in collection.stream():
        
        message.append({
            collection.id: {
                doc.id: doc.to_dict()
            }
        })
print(message)
return message
```

I also tried to insert the return after the for, but it just takes the first value only.

Which as a result gives me:

```
[
    {
        "Test school": {
            "0": {
                "indirizzo": "Test",
                "INFORMATICA E TELECOMUNICAZIONI": {
                    "3A INF": "G1H8JF"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Test School2": {
            "0": {
                "TEST": {
                    "4CCC": "2g45r"
                },
                "indirizzo": "GG1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Test School2": {
            "1": {
                "indirizzo": "gg2",
                "gg": {
                    "asas": "3r3"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I want to get this result instead:

```
{
    {
        "Test School1": {
            "0": {
                "indirizzo": "Test",
                "INFORMATICA E TELECOMUNICAZIONI": {
                    "3A INF": "G1H8JF"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Test School2": {
            "0": {
                "TEST": {
                    "4CCC": "2g45r"
                },
                "indirizzo": "GG1"
            },
            "1": {
                  "indirizzo": "gg2",
                  "gg": {
                      "asas": "3r3"
                  }
              }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried various codes but I cannot adapt them in my specific case on how to merge the two dictionaries. I hope you can help me out.
`collection.id` contains the name of the school (`"Test School1"`)

`doc.id contains` the school account (`"0"`)

`doc.to_dict()` contains the address and all other information

I use Python 3.9.X

I want to clarify that I have also read various answers on this site and I believe that for this specific case it is not a duplicate.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do you want a list of dictionaries? Wouldn't a single large dictionary make more sense?

Comment: I try to get a single dictionary or JSON exactly like in the example I did.

Comment: The first example is a list of dictionaries. The second example is two dictionaries side by side. Neither example shows a single dictionary.

Comment: I don't know how to explain, I would like to combine Test School 2 -> 0 and Test School 2 -> 1 in one dictionary:
`{
  School Test1: {
  0: {
     ...
   },
  1 { 
  ... 
  }
  }
}`

Comment: your expected outcome is a set of dicts, which is not valid in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of keeping track of what you already have somethinf of, is in a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

firestore.collection('schools').document(regione).collection(provincia).document(comune).collections()
message = defaultdict(dict)
for collection in schools:
    print(collection.id)
    for doc in collection.stream():
        message[collection.id][doc.id] = doc.to_dict()
print(message)
return message
```

If you need everything to be split up in multiple dictionaries, you can then break it up afterwards:

```
final_result = [{school: d} for school, d in message.items()]
```

Comment: You're welcome - just FYI: the reason you were getting confusing comments was that you put `{}` around two dictionaries, but didn't provide any keys. If you remove the `{}` around the two inner `dict`s, it becomes a single `dict` - I didn't catch the outer `{}` at first (if they were even there), but @enke correctly remarked that what you wrote was effectively a set of two `dict`s (which can't work, since a `dict` is not 'hashable'). The confusion arises from `{1, 2}` being a `set` and `{1: 2}` being a `dict`, both using `{}` in their literal form.